# Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. I have written data class,dao and typeconverters, but still unable to detect error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

MyData.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_table")
data class MyData(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ListData")
    @TypeConverters(DataTypeConverter::class)
    var mList: List<User> = emptyList(),

    @Embedded
    var user: User
)
```

MyDataDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface MyDataDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(data: MyData)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(data: MyData)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<MyData>>
}
```

DataTypeConverter.kt

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
    import com.google.gson.Gson
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
    
    class DataTypeConverter {
        companion object {
            inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String) =
                fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
    
            @TypeConverter
            fun stringToList(data: String?): List<User> {
                data?.let {
                    return Gson().fromJson(data)
                }
                return emptyList()
            }
    
            @TypeConverter
            fun listToString(users: List<User>): String {
                return Gson().toJson(users)
            }
        }
    }
```

User.kt

```
data class User(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    val firstName: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    val lastName: String
)
```

on build getting this error

error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.

Even after using typeconverters the problem is persistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your DataTypeConverter is wrong you can try change like this :

```
class DataTypeConverter{

    var gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToUserList(data: String?): List<User?>? {
        if (data == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList()
        }
        val listType: Type =
            object : TypeToken<List<User?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<List<User?>>(data, listType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun userDetailListToString(someObjects: List<User?>?): String? {
        return gson.toJson(someObjects)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `@TypeConverters(DataTypeConverter::class)` to `@Database`